# Linking 2 comboxes values to a If statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, combobox

I'm creating small **HTML** page that calculates the price of a phone call depending on the city you select from the **combobox**(First combo is the city from where you're calling and the other one are the cities you're calling to).

Now for some reason the console indicates that the result variable in the last line isn't declared.

Also I'm trying to find a simpler way to substitute the **IF Statements**(I tried it with the switch/case). For some reason the **OK** button opens the Printer Option from Chrome.

The calculator function

```js
function PriceCalc() {
  var time = Number(document.getElementById("time").value);
  var caller = Number(document.getElementById("Caller").value);
  var receiver = Number(document.getElementById("Receiver").value);
  var result = 0;

  if (caller == "1" && receiver == "6") {
    result = time * 1.90;
  } else if (caller == "1" && receiver == "7") {
    result = time * 2.90;

  } else if (caller == "1" && receiver == "8") {
    result = time * 1.65;

  } else if (caller == "2" && receiver == "5") {
    result = time * 2.70;

  } else if (caller == "3" && receiver == "1") {
    result = time * 2.75;


  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " = " + result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="telzir.js"></script>
  <link href="telzir.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="centre">
    <h1>Price Calculator</h1>
    <form>
      <input id="time" placeholder="Minutes Spended">

      <select id="Caller">
        <option value="1">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="2">Ribeirão Preto</option>
        <option value="3">São José dos Campos</option>
        <option value="4">Presidente Prudente</option>
      </select>

      <select id="Receiver">
        <option value="5">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="6">Ribeirão Preto</option>
        <option value="7">São José dos Campos</option>
        <option value="8">Presidente Prudente</option>
      </select>
      <input id="name " type="button" value="Ok" onclick="PriceCalc()">

      <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />

    </form>
    <h1 id="result"> = </h1>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this on my computer in Chrome 68.0.3440.106, the console doesn't indicate that the result variable isn't declared and pressing the OK button doesn't bring up the print dialog. It's possible that there are other variables at play -- maybe you didn't fully refresh the page after making some changes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache).

As for finding a simpler way to express the logic of your application, here are some suggestions:

1. Think about where the data for the calculations is coming from. If it's based on a simple rule, such as the distance between the two locations, you could store one piece of information per location and then calculate the cost using that information. Then you wouldn't need if statements, switch statements, or any other conditional logic.
2. You could create a data structure that stores the multiplier for each set of two locations. In Javascript, you can use objects as dictionaries for this purpose:

```js
function calculateCallCost(minutesSpent, caller, receiver) {
  // This is a dictionary that maps from callers to dictionaries
  // of receivers to multipliers
  // If you haven't used dictionaries before, here's one explanation: https://learn.co/lessons/javascript-objects
  const CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER = {};
  // Here we're creating a new dictionary for caller "São Paulo":
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["São Paulo"] = {};
  // And now we're setting the multiplier for caller "São Paulo" and receiver "Ribeirão Preto" to 1.9:
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["São Paulo"]["Ribeirão Preto"] = 1.9;
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["São Paulo"]["São José dos Campos"] = 2.9;
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["São Paulo"]["Presidente Prudente"] = 1.65;
  // Now we're creating a dictionary for caller "2"
  // Here we use a shortcut to set the multipliers as we create the dictionary:
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["Ribeirão Preto"] = {
    "São Paulo": 2.7
  };
  // If we wanted to, we could have done the same for caller "1":
  // CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["1"] = {"6": 1.9, "7": 2.9, "8": 1.65}
  CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER["São José dos Campos"] = {
    "São Paulo": 2.75
  };

  let receiverToMultiplier = CALLER_TO_RECEIVER_TO_MULTIPLIER[caller];
  if (receiverToMultiplier !== undefined) {
    let multiplier = receiverToMultiplier[receiver];
    if (multiplier !== undefined) {
      return multiplier * minutesSpent;
    }
  }
  let multiplier = receiverToMultiplier[receiver];
  if (multiplier === undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
}

function PriceCalc() {
  var time = Number(document.getElementById("time").value);
  var caller = document.getElementById("Caller").value;
  var receiver = document.getElementById("Receiver").value;

  let cost = calculateCallCost(time, caller, receiver);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " = " + cost;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="telzir.js"></script>
  <link href="telzir.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="centre">
    <h1>Price Calculator</h1>
    <form>
      <input id="time" placeholder="Minutes Spended">

      <!-- Note that I've changed the values to strings. You don't need to do this, but I found it easier to read. It does make typos more of an issue, and if you're worried about that in your code, you could store the strings in variables. -->
      <select id="Caller">
        <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="Ribeirão Preto">Ribeirão Preto</option>
        <option value="São José dos Campos">São José dos Campos</option>
        <option value="Presidente Prudente">Presidente Prudente</option>
      </select>

      <select id="Receiver">
        <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="Ribeirão Preto">Ribeirão Preto</option>
        <option value="São José dos Campos">São José dos Campos</option>
        <option value="Presidente Prudente">Presidente Prudente</option>
      </select>
      <input id="name " type="button" value="Ok" onclick="PriceCalc()">

      <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />

    </form>
    <h1 id="result"> = </h1>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Of course there's many other approaches and many incremental improvements you could make to your code, depending on your goals and how much time you have, but maybe this will get you started. Good luck :)